# How to get all "collections" name in one line output from "for loop" (python)

Tags: python, scripting

Currently I have this code:

```
col = bpy.data.collections
for i in col:
    list = i.name
    print(list)
```

Output:

```
Collection 1
Collection 2
Collection 3
Collection 4
Collection 5
>>>
```

how to get output list like bellow?

```
['Collection 1','Collection 2','Collection 3','Collection 4','Collection 5']
>>>
```

Comment: Have answered since blender collections use a mapping that makes them similar to both dictionaries and lists, and can get the list of names ob objects  in a blender  collection with the keys method.  However this question is very (x 4) close to being off topic as a generic python question as  It is not the purpose of this site to teach basic python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bpy_collections.**

Blender uses a collection that can be accessed like a dictionary (string key) or like a list (integer index)

The name of the object in the collection is also its keys. For a collection the names of all objects in the collections can be gained quickly via the collections keys.

```
D.collections.keys()
```

(`D.collections.values()` is the values, and `.items()` the key, value pairs.

Or via list comprehension.

```
[c.name for c in D.collections]
```

Or lastly using a for loop

```
>>> cols = []
>>> for c in D.collections:
...     cols.append(c.name)
...     
>>> cols
['Collection 1', 'Collection 1.001', 'Collection 1.002', 'Collection 1.003']
```

*Note: could have also used `cols = list()` here since list is a python type. In as much as can define it as something else `list = "something else"` it's not recommended practice*

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, sorry i don't realize if it more relevant to basic python, basically i'm new in python and i just try to create a simple script to speedup my workflow :)
since it's not relevant again to this site
should i delete this post ?